# Apex Code not covering wrapper class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I have been unable to cover more than 57% of my apex code. I believe it has to do with my wrapper class **SampleReqItemWrapper**. I notice that code is not covered anywhere that has has **wrappers[selectedIndex]**. Could I get help covering this portion of my apex code.

My Apex Class:

```
public class ManageListController{
public List<SmplReqItemWrapper> wrappers {get; set;}
public Sample_Request__c smr{get; set;} 
public Integer selectedIndex {get; set;}
public integer rowNumber {get;set;}
private Integer nextIdent = 0;

public ManageListController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    this.smr = (sample_request__c) controller.getrecord(); 
    wrappers = new List<SmplReqItemWrapper>();
    if( smr.Id != null ){
        list<Sample_Request_Item__c> SRIList = [Select Id, Name, FDA_Codes__c , Product_List__c, Sample_Request__c, Unit_Weight__c, 
                                               UOM__c, Total_Qty_Wt__c, Requested_Qty__c, Item_Name__c, Item_Remark__c
                                               from Sample_Request_Item__c where Sample_Request__c =: smr.Id];
        for( Sample_Request_Item__c SRI : SRIList ){
            wrappers.add( new SmplReqItemWrapper( nextIdent++, SRI ) );
        }
    }else{
       wrappers.add( new SmplReqItemWrapper( nextIdent++, new Sample_Request_Item__c() ) );
    }
}

public void delWrapper(){
    system.debug('selectedIndex'+selectedIndex);
    try{
        if( selectedIndex != null ){
           if( wrappers[selectedIndex].item.Id != null ){
                Delete wrappers[selectedIndex].item;
            }
            wrappers.remove(selectedIndex);
            nextIdent--;
        }
        if( wrappers.size() > selectedIndex ){
            for( Integer i = selectedIndex; i < wrappers.size(); i++ ){
                wrappers[i].ident = i;
            }
        }
        selectedIndex = null;
    }catch( Exception ex ){
        Apexpages.addMessages(ex);
    }
}

public void addRows (){
    try{
        wrappers.add( new SmplReqItemWrapper(nextIdent++, new Sample_Request_Item__c()) );
    }catch( Exception ex ){
        Apexpages.addMessages(ex);
    }
}

public PageReference saveRequest() {  
    PageReference pr;
    Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
    system.debug('wrappers'+wrappers);
    try{
        Boolean isError = false; 
        list <Sample_Request_Item__c> itemList = new List<Sample_Request_Item__c> ();
        for (SmplReqItemWrapper wrap : wrappers){

            if( wrap.item.Product_List__c != null ){
                if( String.isBlank(wrap.item.UOM__c) ){
                    wrap.item.UOM__c.addError( 'UOM is required.' );
                    isError = true;
                }
                if( String.isBlank(wrap.item.FDA_Codes__c) ){
                    wrap.item.FDA_Codes__c.addError( 'FDA Codes is required.' );
                    isError = true;
                }
                if( wrap.item.Requested_Qty__c  ==  null ){
                    wrap.item.Requested_Qty__c.addError( 'Item code is required.' );
                    isError = true;
                }

            }else{
                wrap.item.Product_List__c.addError( 'Item code is required.' );
                isError = true;
            }
            if( !isError ){
                itemList.add( wrap.item );
            }
        }
        if( !isError ){
            upsert smr;  
            for(Sample_Request_Item__c item : itemList ){
                item.Sample_Request__c = smr.Id;
            }
            upsert itemList;
            pr = new PageReference('/'+smr.Id);
        }else{
            Database.rollback(sp);
        }

    }catch( Exception ex ){
        Apexpages.addMessages(ex);
        Database.rollback(sp);
    }       
    return pr;
}

public void productSelected(){
    system.debug('selectedIndex'+selectedIndex);
    try{
        if( selectedIndex != null ){
            SmplReqItemWrapper wrap = wrappers[selectedIndex];
            if( wrap.item.Product_List__c != null ){
                Product_List__c productList = [Select Id, Name, Item_Name__c  from Product_List__c Where Id =: wrap.item.Product_List__c Limit 1];
                wrap.ItemName = productList.Item_Name__c;

            }else{
                wrap.item = new Sample_Request_Item__c();
                wrap.item.Product_List__c.addError( 'Item code is required.' );
                wrap.ItemName = '';
            }           
        }   
    }catch( Exception ex ){
        Apexpages.addMessages(ex);
    }   
}

public void quantityChanged(){
    system.debug('selectedIndex'+selectedIndex);
    try{
        if( selectedIndex != null ){
            SmplReqItemWrapper wrap = wrappers[selectedIndex];
            if( wrap.item.Requested_Qty__c != null && wrap.UnitWeight != null ){
                wrap.totalQty = wrap.UnitWeight * wrap.item.Requested_Qty__c;
            }else{
                wrap.totalQty = 0;
            }       
        }
    }catch( Exception ex ){
        Apexpages.addMessages(ex);
    }   
}

public void uomChanged(){
    system.debug('selectedIndex'+selectedIndex);
    try{
        if( selectedIndex != null ){
            SmplReqItemWrapper wrap = wrappers[selectedIndex];
            Product_List__c productList = [Select Id, Baked_Wt_KG__c, Net_Case_WT__c  from Product_List__c Where Id =: wrap.item.Product_List__c Limit 1];
            if( wrap.item.UOM__c == 'PCS' ){
                wrap.UnitWeight = productList.Baked_Wt_KG__c; 
                wrap.totalQty = 0;
            }else if(wrap.item.UOM__c == 'CASES'){
                wrap.UnitWeight = productList.Net_Case_WT__c;
            }else{
                wrap.UnitWeight = 0;
            } 
            quantityChanged();      
        }
    }catch( Exception ex ){
        Apexpages.addMessages(ex);
    }   
}


public class SmplReqItemWrapper {  
    public Sample_Request_Item__c item {get;set;}
    public String ItemName {get;set;}
    public decimal UnitWeight {get;set;}
    public decimal totalQty {get;set;}   
    public integer rowNumber {get;set;}
    public Integer ident {get; public set;}    
    //constructor  
    public SmplReqItemWrapper(Integer inIdent, Sample_Request_Item__c item )  {
        this.ident = inIdent;
        this.item = item; 
        this.ItemName = this.item.Item_Name__c;
        this.UnitWeight = this.item.Unit_Weight__c; 
        this.totalQty = this.item.Total_Qty_Wt__c;
     }

   }  
}
```

My Test Class:

```
@istest
public class ManageListController_Test{

static testmethod void unittest4 () {
   //create sample request 
   Sample_Request__c smr = new sample_request__c ();
   insert smr;

   ID smrID = smr.ID;

  product_list__C pl =new product_list__c ();
  insert pl;   
  ID prodLID = pl.ID; 

  list <sample_request_item__C> smri = new list <sample_Request_item__C> ();   
    sample_request_item__C sri = new sample_request_item__C ( FDA_Codes__c = 
'03AGT99', Product_List__C = pl.Id, Sample_Request__c = smrID, UOM__c = 
'PCS', Requested_Qty__c = decimal.valueof(5), Item_Remark__c = 'item remarks 
test');
smri.add(sri);

sample_request_item__C sri2 = new sample_request_item__C ( FDA_Codes__c = '03AGT99', Product_List__C = pl.id, Sample_Request__c = smrID,    
                                                            UOM__c = 'PCS', Requested_Qty__c = null, Item_Remark__c = 'item remarks test3');
smri.add(sri2);

sample_request_item__C sri3 = new sample_request_item__C (  FDA_Codes__c = '03AGT99', Product_List__C = pl.Id, Sample_Request__c = smrID,    
                                                            UOM__c = '', Requested_Qty__c = decimal.valueof(3), Item_Remark__c = 'item remarks test3');
smri.add(sri3);

sample_request_item__C sri4 = new sample_request_item__C (  FDA_Codes__c = '', Product_List__C = pl.id, Sample_Request__c = smrID,    
                                                            UOM__c = 'PCS', Requested_Qty__c = decimal.valueof(0), Item_Remark__c = 'item remarks test3');
smri.add(sri4);    

sample_request_item__C sri5 = new sample_request_item__C (  FDA_Codes__c = '03AGT99', Product_List__C = pl.id, Sample_Request__c = smrID,    
                                                            UOM__c = 'CASES', Requested_Qty__c = decimal.valueof(0), Item_Remark__c = 'item remarks test3');
smri.add(sri5); 
insert smri;
system.debug('Added new sample request item');


sample_request_item__C item = new sample_request_item__C();
integer indent = 1;
//String ItemName = 'itemname';
decimal UnitWeight = decimal.valueOf(1);
decimal totalQty  = decimal.valueof(4); 

managelistcontroller.SmplReqItemWrapper wrap = new managelistcontroller.SmplReqItemWrapper(1, item);
    wrap.itemName = 'test';
    wrap.totalQty = 0.4;
    wrap.UnitWeight = 0.085;
    wrap.item.UOM__c = 'PCS';
    //wrap.item.Product_List__c = pl.Id;
list<managelistcontroller.SmplReqItemWrapper> wrap_list = new list<managelistcontroller.SmplReqItemWrapper> ();
wrap_list.add(wrap);



test.startTest();   
    pageReference pr = Page.Sample_Request_Form;
    test.setCurrentPage(Page.Sample_Request_Form);
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('std', smr.Id);
    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController (smr);
    ManageListController ext = new ManageListController (sc);    
    system.debug(pr);
    ext.delWrapper();
    ext.addRows();
    ext.saveRequest();
    ext.productSelected();
    ext.quantityChanged();
    ext.uomChanged();
  test.stopTest();



 }
}
```

Comment: As an FYI you have not written a unit test here, you have written a smoke test. Kinda like flipping on the right switch but not checking to see if the bulb was burnt out.....In other words all you are doing is proving that no uncaught or swallowed errors occurred.

Answer (score 1):

The clue is:

> I notice that code is not covered anywhere that has has
>   wrappers[selectedIndex].

So lets sit back and think on that......

The lines before it are

```
if( selectedIndex != null ){
```

So that would mean in order to enter I need `selectedIndex` to NOT be null...

Review test class...

Ahh, Say self, I am not setting it...

Not saying this will not cause other problems to surface now that you get inside the if block though (NPE, Index out of bounds, bad data etc), as I did not review your **smoke test** for other issues but try setting:

```
ext.selectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: Hi Eric. That unfortunately didn't work, but I do understand your logic for why I should of included that line. Thanks for breaking that down for me.

Comment: @CReyes7 - Define "Didn't work" I bet either you had an error but if you made it to the IF then it DID enter the If

Comment: What I meant by didn't work is that it did not make any changes to my code coverage. My  `if(selectedIndez !=null) {` portions of my code were previously covered by the test code I had written. I think the issue I am facing is specifically related to portions of my apex code that have the line  
          `SmplReqItemWrapper wrap = wrappers[selectedIndex];`

Comment: @CReyes7 - remove the try catch blocks around your code and you will see why. Or at the least debug the error.